# Effect of FDE for data recovery

Tags: disk-encryption

Assume that I fully encrypt an unused USB (FDE), then format it and copy plaintext files. If the files are deleted from USB by using a secure wipe, does FDE that was first applied decrease the possibility of recovering files?

Comment: Well, it certainly decreases the possibility if you don't decrypt the drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, no.

I'm reading this version of the question as

> *I fully encrypt an unused USB (FDE), then format it*

equivalent to **randomize** then **format**. Then

> files are deleted from USB by using a secure wipe

boils down to simply how good your secure wipe functions. The past history of the media can make manual examination a little bit more difficult as zeroes are easier to filter out than random. But the bottom line is still how well your secure wipe functions.